# Restricting a report to not show clients that closed a product but still have another one opened?

Tags: sql, oracle, report, intervals

I need to make a report that will return active and inactive clients during a certain period of time.

This is based on some products that have an opening and a closing date. Clients that closed a product, but still had another one open don't need to show up. My problem is that I don't know how to restrict the report in order to make this happen. I have tried to add a `not exists` clause like:

```
    WITH my_with_as AS 
( 
       SELECT p.product_id, 
              p.client_id, 
              p.opening_date, 
              p.ending_date 
       FROM   products p 
       WHERE  p.opening_date BETWEEN report_start_date AND    report_end_date 
       OR     p.ending_date BETWEEN report_open_date AND    report_end_date) 
SELECT cl.d_start, 
       CASE 
              WHEN cl.d_stop BETWEEN report_start_date AND    report_end_date THEN my_with_as.ending_date
              ELSE NULL 
       END 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT 
                     ( 
                            SELECT Min(d1.opening_date) 
                            FROM   my_with_as d1 
                            WHERE  d1.client_id=c.client_id) d_start, 
                     ( 
                            SELECT Max(d2.ending_date) 
                            FROM   my_with_as d2 
                            WHERE  d2.client_id=c.client_id) d_stop, 
                     c.* 
              FROM   clients c) cl, 
       my_with_as 
WHERE  cl.client_id=my_with_as.client_id 
AND    NOT EXISTS 
       ( 
              SELECT p.product_id 
              FROM   products p 
              WHERE  my_with_as.client_id = p.client_id 
              AND    p.product_id<>my_with_as.product_id 
              AND    Nvl(p.ending_date,report_end_date+1)>report_end_date 
              AND    p.start_date < my_with_as.ending_date
```

where `my_with_as` is a with as query with all the products that opened or closed during the period of time of the report.

Problem is for a reporting period of `01.05.2014 - 04.04.2015` and a client that has:

```
-product_1: opened on 04.04.2001, closed on 25.07.2014

-product_2: opened on 04.04.2010, closed on 25.03.2015

-product_3: opened on 01.01.2015, closed on 04.04.2015
```

my report shows both the **1st product** and the **3rd one** even though it shouldn't show anything. Is there a way to verify if the intervals of the products overlap? Any hint or help is highly appreciated as this is has been driving me nuts for 3 days now.

---

*---- EDIT (copied table definitions from comments to the question ) -----*

the products table: `product_id, client_id, opening_date, ending_date.` 

the clients table has just the client_id - i simplified it for test purposes. 

the report will have 2 dates as parameters: start_report, end_report –

Comment: It would help us better answer the question if we knew the table definitions -- what tables are in play and what columns do they have?

Comment: the products table: product_id, client_id, opening_date, ending_date. the clients table has just the client_id - i simplified it for test purposes. the report will have 2 dates as parameters: start_report, end_report

Comment: Also, posting the complete query (instead of the part that is not working) would help.

Comment: hi, i posted the whole thing i'm testing right now; the report_end_date and report_start_date are the report's parameters aka the period of time during which i need to retrived data. thank you!

Comment: sql formatting makes it easier for people to read

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is query you are looking for, or at least it will be useful for you:

```
with report as (select date '2014-05-01' r1, date '2015-04-04' r2 from dual),
mwa AS (
  SELECT p.product_id, p.client_id, p.opening_date, p.ending_date, r1, r2
    FROM products p cross join report r
    WHERE p.opening_date BETWEEN r1 AND r2 OR p.ending_date BETWEEN r1 AND r2 )
SELECT cl.d_start, CASE WHEN cl.d_stop BETWEEN r1 AND r2 THEN mwa.ending_date END d_stop
  FROM
    (SELECT
        (SELECT MIN(opening_date) FROM mwa WHERE client_id = c.client_id) d_start,
        (SELECT MAX(ending_date) FROM mwa WHERE client_id = c.client_id) d_stop, c.*
      FROM clients c) cl join mwa on mwa.client_id = cl.client_id
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT p.product_id from products p 
        WHERE mwa.client_id = p.client_id AND p.product_id<>mwa.product_id
          and not (p.opening_date BETWEEN r1 AND r2 
            OR p.ending_date between r1 and r2))
```

It returns no rows for given examples, because one row does not belong to analyzed periods - so we don't want rest of rows for this client.
Please replace dates in first line to change period, but use notation 'yyyy-mm-dd', or use `to_date()` there.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0a20/1)

In SQLFiddle I added one row for other client to test solution, so we have one row returned.

I suspect that this query may be simplified, but I didn't want too interfere in your code too.

---

**Edit** - according to comments:

```
with report as (select date '2015-02-01' r1, date '2015-04-03' r2 from dual),
p1 as (select product_id pid, client_id cid, opening_date d1, ending_date d2, r1, r2 
  from products p cross join report r ),
p2 as (select pid, cid, d1, d2,
    case when ( d1 < r2 and (d2 is null or d2 > r1) ) then 1 else 0 end overlap,
    case when ( d1 < r2 and d2 is not null and d2 < r2 ) then 1 else 0 end closed
  from p1)
select * from p2 order by cid, pid

PID               CID D1         D2            OVERLAP     CLOSED
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
product_1           1 2014-04-04 2014-07-25          0          1 
product_2           1 2015-01-04 2015-03-25          1          1 
product_3           1 2015-01-01 2015-04-01          1          1 
product_1           2 2015-01-01 2015-04-04          1          0 
product_1           3 2015-04-04 2015-07-25          0          0 
product_2           3 2015-01-01 2015-04-04          1          0

overlap = 1 means that product was "active" in report period, probably these are the
            only rows which interests you
closed  = 1 means that product has closed status at the end of period
```

The query above gives us extended information about each product. Now you can filter only rows
with overlap = 1 and work with them. Example of what you can do next is:

```
with report as (select date '2015-02-01' r1, date '2015-07-20' r2 from dual),
p1 as (select product_id pid, client_id cid, opening_date d1, ending_date d2, r1, r2 
  from products p cross join report r ),
p as (select pid, cid, d1, d2, r2,
    case when ( d1 < r2 and (d2 is null or d2 > r1) ) then 1 else 0 end overlap,
    case when ( d1 < r2 and d2 is not null and d2 < r2 ) then 1 else 0 end closed
  from p1)
select distinct c.name, d1, nvl(d2, r2) d2
  from p join clients c on c.client_id = p.cid
  where overlap = 1 and not exists (
    select 1 from p tmp where overlap = 1 and closed = 1 
      and cid = p.cid and pid <> p.pid )

NAME       D1         D2       
---------- ---------- ----------
Jones      2015-01-01 2015-04-04 
Smith      2015-01-01 2015-04-04
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply! problem is i need to show clients that for example had a product opened at 04.04.2001, closed on 25.07.2014, then opened a new one on 01.01.2015, closed on 04.04.2015. for a reporting period of: 01.05.2014 - 31.07.2014 i need to show the 1st product as closed, for a reporting period of 01.01.2015 - 04.04.2015 i need to show the 2nd product as opened. basically if a client has a product open and opens another one i don't need to report it, if he doesn't have an open product and he opens one then i need to report it .i'm kinda bad at explaining hope it makes sense:S

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, you are not the best at explaining ;-) 
I have read carefully your examples and main topic several times and best I could invent is in edited section in answer. I think it's what you want or close to that.